# How to cut and then paste previous item in clipboard in vim?

Tags: vim

In vim I copied the string `ABCD` to my clipboard. Now I want to replace certain words in a paragraph of text by doing <kbd>c-e</kbd> (this deletes and immediately puts me in insert mode). But when I paste it will paste the thing I just cut overriding my ABCD.

One solution I came up with is:

```
c-e 

ctrl-o

"0P
```

But that just seems way too long. Is there a faster alternative to that?

Comment: What about going into visual mode and pasting?  `vep`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While copying a string, place the cursor at the start of the string, then type

> "ayw

where **"a** means the name of the register(its like a storage) and **yw** means copy(yank) the word into that register.
There are 26 registers, one for each letter of the alphabet.

When you want to paste the content, type

> "ap

where **p** means to paste. Then use the vim repeat command **.** to repeat last action
You can store strings in different registers and paste them whenever u want.
to set contents of all registers type

> :reg

For more information go to

[Using Vim's named registers](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-vims-named-registers/)

[Vim registers: The basics and beyond](https://www.brianstorti.com/vim-registers/)

[Vim tips and tricks](https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~kuperman/help/vim/registers.html)

Answer (score 1):

The last thing you yanked is always available in register `0` so, in your case, you only have to do:

```
<C-e><C-r>0<Esc>
```

See `:help i_ctrl-r`.

But yeah, there's a much simpler way for one-off puts:

```
vep
```

or, if you need to do those changes several times:

```
ve"0p
```

Comment: That simpler way, `vep`, it will only work once, won't it? After the first run the default register will be replaced with the word we pasted over – and since the OP mentions they want to replace **certain words** I fail to see how it can help in this particular case.

Comment: `vep` is the exact solution to the problem as described by the OP. For sequential changes the OP could simply use `.` or, if he really likes to press keys, `ve"0p`. Answer edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [yankstack](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack), which simplifies your use case.
This make it easy to cycle against your yank buffer when you paste.
I've personally remapped the keys to space (my leader key).

Here is an extract of my `.vimrc`:

```
if &runtimepath =~ 'vim-yankstack'
 let g:yankstack_map_keys = 0
 nmap <leader>p <Plug>yankstack_substitute_older_paste
 nmap <leader>P <Plug>yankstack_substitute_newer_paste
endif
```

In your case, you just press space p right after having pasted your text. This will replace the word pasted with the last entry in your buffer. You can repeat pressingspace p if you need to go deeper in the history.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "stamping" approach; this allows you to stay in normal mode and is just one keystroke. Add this mapping:

```
nnoremap S diw"0P
```

Then press `S` to "stamp" over any word your cursor is on with what you've yanked.
So, an example of the full routine:

```
1. ye
2. <move cursor over the word you wish to replace with the yank>
3. S
```

And, of course, if `S` is used, chose something else, e.g. `ww`. 
This is a well known approach; see this documentation for variations and details: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_word_with_yanked_text.